# Extracting the public certificate from a certificate

Tags: c, openssl, certificate

I would like to programmatically generate a certificate that contain only the public key using openssl.

So I basically need to do the following but using code.

```
openssl x509 -in certificate.crt -pubkey
```

Digging a bit it seem that I need to create a new certificate and copy all the information except the private key in it.

```
X509 * pNewKey = X509_new();
... Copy all the needed information ...

PEM_write_bio_X509(bioKey, &pNewKey, NULL, NULL);
```

Does someone have a better method?

Comment: "Extracting the public certificate from a certificate" - did you mean to write the public key? Or something else?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I would like to programmatically generate a certificate that contain only the public key

To set the public key, take your public key in `EVP_PKEY` format and call `X509_set_pubkey`. Building upon your example code:

```
X509* x509 = X509_new();
EVP_PKEY* pkey = /***/;

int rc = X509_set_pubkey(x509, pkey);
ASSERT(rc == 1);

BIO* bio = BIO_new_file("filename.txt", "w");
ASSERT(bio != NULL);

rc = PEM_write_bio_X509(bio, x509, NULL, NULL);
ASSERT(rc == 1);

...
BIO_free(bio);
EVP_PKEY_free(pkey);
X509_free(x509);
```

For completeness, OpenSSL will save a certificate with no attributes, no version, no public key, and no signature.

---

> So I basically need to do the following but using code.
>
> openssl x509 -in certificate.crt -pubkey

OK, this is a different question. The above command will print the public key.

Use `x509_get_pubkey`:

```
EVP_PKEY* pkey = X509_get_pubkey(X509* x509);
```

Once you have the `EVP_PKEY`, you can get the type. You need to supply this function because OpenSSL does not provide it:

```
int EVP_PKEY_get_type(EVP_PKEY *pkey)
{
    AC_ASSERT(pkey);
    if (!pkey)
        return NID_undef;

    return EVP_PKEY_type(pkey->type);
}
```

Then, depending on the type, you can print the key:

```
if(type == EVP_PKEY_RSA || type == EVP_PKEY_RSA2)
{
    RSA* rsa = EVP_PKEY_get1_RSA(pkey);
    RSA_print_fp(stdout, rsa, 0);
    RSA_free(rsa);
}
...
```

You have to break out the keys by type and then call the respective `XXX_print_fp` because OpenSSL does not provide an `EVP_PKEY_print_fp`.

The `get1` in `EVP_PKEY_get1_RSA` means the reference count on the key is bumped. So you have to call a `*_free` on it. A `get0` does *not* bump the reference count, and does not need a call to `*_free`.